# How retrieve email editor from google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for how can i get the editor of a specific cell in google sheets.
My problem was to find Who write **Accept** in a specific cell.
I looked from web and get the answer after mining a bit in many sites.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the spreadsheet
2. Click Tools/Script Editor
3. Inside code.gs insert script below

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Página1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column
      var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().protect();
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      var editors = protection.getEditors();
      protection.remove();
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      var nCell = r.offset(0, 2);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ){ //is empty?
        var time = new Date();
        time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT", "HH:mm:ss");       
        nextCell.setValue(time); 
        nCell.setValue(editors);      
      };
    };
  };
}
```